# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() using Bing API

Tags: php, bing-api

I am getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error. Am using Bing API. The code which contains the errors is.`<?php
 foreach($obj->SearchResponse->Web->Results as $value){
 ?>`

Answer (score 0):

use `var_dump` and make sure that `$obj->SearchResponse->Web->Results` is indeed an array.